# aligning XSL element to the right of page

Tags: html, css

Is there any way is XSL to align the following element to the right of the page after page generation and XSLT?

```
<RadioButton>               
    <Name>myRadio</Name>
</RadioButton>
```

Where `RadioButton` is a template defined as `<input radio...etc>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once the page is generated you will need to do cosmetic alignments using cascading style sheets or something.

so in your xsl you might have template to make it like

```
<input type="radio" name="blah" class="moo" value="blah" />
```

and in .css have

```
.moo{
float:right;
}
```

or you can use an inline style like

```
<input type="radio" name="blah" style="float:left;" value="blah" />
```

Comment: i'm going with the inline style...does float:left mean align element to the right?